# How to pass null DateTime object as a param to MySQL db?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am new in db. I have such the table

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I use Insert query from my C# code like this

```
string date = workInfo.EndTime == null ? "NULL" : $"'{((DateTime)workInfo.EndTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss")}'"; 
string queryStr = $"INSERT INTO `test`.`test_table` (`date`) VALUES ({date})";
```

in this case if the value is null I pass `NULL` otherwise I format the date and anyway pass it as a string.

The question is - is there a way to pass directly `DateTime?` object? Like here

```
DateTime? date = workInfo.EndTime;
string queryStr = $"INSERT INTO `test`.`test_table` (`date`) VALUES ({date})";
```

Because whey I try to do it I get an error:

1. if DateTime is null so the query looks like this

   INSERT INTO `test`.`test_table` (`date`) VALUES ()
2. if there is a date so I get an exception about incorrect date format

Comment: Don't interpolate data in queries, **use parameters**. This closes your SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: ```string queryStr = $"INSERT INTO `test`.`test_table` (`date`) VALUES (NULLIF({date}, ''))";```. If empty string provided as a value, then NULLIF() converts it to NULL else provided value is returned. Maybe, quoting needed also: ```NULLIF('{date}', '')```.

Comment: It's `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` to get datestamps in the format MySQL wants (`mm` not `MM` for minutes).